# MongoDB find query with multiple query field using $or

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking for a Mongo query for finding data in the following document.

```
{
    "key1": [{
        "subkey1": ["america.south.gas"],
        "subkey2": ["9898989898"]
    }],

    "key2": [{
            "subkey1": ["america"],
            "subkey2": ["hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9"]
        },
        {
            "subkey1": ["america.south.gas","america"],
            "subkey2": ["hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9"]
        },
        {
            "subkey1": ["america.south.#"],
            "subkey2": ["sjadkjsahdkjsahdj989s89d8sa98d9sa"]
        }]
}
```

I want only `subkey2` only of above mentioned document as following output:

```
"subkey2": ["hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9"] 
"subkey2": ["sjadkjsahdkjsahdj989s89d8sa98d9sa"]
```

Now I want to fetch data with following query:-

```
db.collectionName.find({$or:[ 
        {"key2.subkey1": "america.south.gas"},   
        {"key1.subkey1": "america.south.#"} 
    ]},
    {"_id": 0, "key2.subkey2.$": 1}
);
```

But it is showing me this error:

```
{ 
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0), 
    "ok" : 0, 
    "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command: BadValue: positional operator (key1.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier", 
    "code" : 96 
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve this for getting specific field with multiple query field in Mongo find operation??

Comment: "But it is showing me error" ... could you update your question to show us this error? Also, this kind of question is often made clearer by including an example document showing exacty what output you are expecting. This is often the least ambiguous way of expressing your requirements.

Comment: The question includes the `java` tag, is this relevant? Are you trying to express this query using the Mongo Java driver? Or using the Mongo shell?

Comment: I am trying it using Mongo shell and through java also..and i want only subkey2 only of above mentioned document as following output:-               
                                                                                                        "subkey2": ["hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9"]                                                         "subkey2": ["sjadkjsahdkjsahdj989s89d8sa98d9sa"]

Comment: and the error, which i am getting is :-                                                              db.wildcards.find({$or:[{"key1.subkey1":"america.south.gas"},{"key1.subkey1":"america.south.#"}]},{"_id":0,"key1.subkey2.$":1})
Error: error: {
        "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command: BadValue: positional operator (key1.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier",
        "code" : 96
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error ...

> Error: error: { "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0), "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command: BadValue: positional operator (key1.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier", "code" : 96 }

.. is caused by this projection:

```
"key2.subkey2.$": 1
```

Soecifically, the positional operator: `$`.

According to the comments above, you ...

> want only subkey2 only of above mentioned document as following output:- "subkey2": ["hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9"] "subkey2": ["sjadkjsahdkjsahdj989s89d8sa98d9sa"]

The following command ...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$key2'}, 
    // find the documents having key2.subkey1 = 'america.south.#' or key2.subkey1 = 'america.south.gas'
    {$match:{'key2.subkey1':{$in:['america.south.#','america.south.gas']}}},
    // limit the output to only those key2.subkey2 entries for which the associated key2.subkey1 match the previous $match clause
    {$group:{_id:0,'subkey2':{$push:'$key2.subkey2'}}},
    // only return subkey2
    {$project: {_id: 0, 'subkey2':1}}
])
```

... will return:

```
{
    "subkey2" : [ 
        [ 
            "hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9"
        ], 
        [ 
            "sjadkjsahdkjsahdj989s89d8sa98d9sa"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank @glytching . It works for me.One more thing i am getting this response via java-script code:-{_batch: [{subkey2: [[hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9, sadsadsadsafdsafsafd], [hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9, sadsadsadsafdsafsafd]]]}], _cursor: {}}.                Can i ignore "_batch" and "_cursor" keys from response...

Comment: That looks like whatever JS MongoDB driver you are using wraps the raw response in a document containing `_batch` and `_cursor`> I'm guessing that the JS MongoDB driver allows you to interrogate the wrapped response to only read the `_batch` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also i am executing same query with 5000 records, this is taking approx 2000ms to retrieve data. How better can i optimize that??

Comment: Run you query with `.expain()` and review the results to see why it is taking so long.

Comment: response:-{"waitedMS" : NumberLong(0), "stages" : [  "$cursor" : {"query" : {},
"queryPlanner" : {"plannerVersion" : 1,
                                        "namespace" : "admin.bulkData",
                                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                                        "parsedQuery" : {
                                                "$and" : [ ]
                                        },
 "winningPlan" : {
"stage" : "COLLSCAN",
"filter" : {
 "$and" : [ ]
 },
 "direction" : "forward"
 },
"rejectedPlans" : [ ]
}}},"ok" : 1}

Answer (score 0):

@glytching, If i need output like that as below given then what need to change in query and also no duplicate output value.

{
    "subkey2" : [ "hsadjsahjsahdjsah879878u9","sjadkjsahdkjsahdj989s89d8sa98d9sa"]

}